# Rails 2.3.5: How does one access code inside of lib/directory/file.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a file so I can share a method amongst many models in lib/foo/bar_woo.rb. Inside of bar_woo.rb I defined the following:

```
module BarWoo
  def hello
   puts "hello"
  end
end
```

Then in my model I'm doing something like:

```
  def MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
      include Foo::BarWoo
      def some_method
         Foo::BarWoo.hello
      end
  end
```

The interpreter is complaining that it expected bar_woo.rb to define Foo::BarWoo.

The Agile Web Development with Rails book states that if files contain classes or modules and the files are named using the lowercase form of the class or module name, then Rails will load the file automatically. I didn't require it because of this.

What is the correct way to define the code and what is the right way to call it in my model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to try:

```
module Foo
  module BarWoo
    def hello
      puts "hello"
    end
  end
end
```

Also for calling you won't call it with `Foo::BarWhoo.hello` - that would have to make it a class method. However `include`ing the module should enable you to call it with just `hello`.

Comment: I was under the impression that the directory structure would make it so I can omit the top level module. I will try that.

Comment: I've written the module like that, but accessing it as Foo::BarWoo.hello from my model isn't working.. says hello is not a defined method.

Comment: Have you included the module?

Answer (score 3):

Files in subdirectories of `/lib` are not automatically `require`'d by default. The cleanest way to handle this is to add a new initializer under `config/initializers` that loads your library module for you.

In: `config/initializers/load_my_libraries.rb`  Pick whatever name you want.

```
require(File.join(RAILS_ROOT, "lib", "foo", "bar_woo"))
```

Once it has been `require`'d, you should be able to `include` it at will.

Comment: Do I still need to have module Foo followed by module BarWoo in the file in that case? Is module Foo implicit if it's in the directory Foo? I'm not sure what kind of magic Rails does when working with lib. Also from the controller stand point of view, do I just call Foo::BarWoo.method or just method?

Comment: It's not implicit, as far as I know, so you most likely still need to nest it in your bar_woo.rb file.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is twofold.

1. You need to use the outer Foo scope to define BarWoo
2. You have defined hello as an instance method, then tried to call it on the class.

Define your method using `def self.hello` instead of `def hello`

```
module Foo
  module BarWoo
    def self.hello
      puts "hello"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do

```
module Foo::Barwoo; end;
```