# writing tests for modules in lib folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, testing

I want to write unit tests for a  module file I created and put it in lib directory. Under test/unit directory, I have created a `mylib_test.rb` file. In the file I have required mylib. When I run `rake test:units` it gives a `const_missing: uninitialized constant mylib::constantname` error. I'm thinking that this is because it is not loading the rails environment since the constant is defined in one of the initializers file. I'm I correct? How do I get it to work? What is the best way to write unit tests for modules?

I'm using rails 3.1.3 and the model works perfectly when I run the application both from terminal and from a browser.

Comment: +1 for this. I would like to know more too about how to test custom modules in Rails 3.1

Comment: I did rake environment test:units, but it still did not work. I thought that was supposed to load the environment, but it still did not work

Comment: What I did (usgin RSpec2 instead of Test:Unit), having my module crawl in the extras/ folder like this: extras/crawl/module.rb is to add duplicate these paths in my spec folders, like this spec/extras/crawl/module_spec.rb. Then I also created an initializer that requires customizations like 'crawl/string'. Thought my custom classes are autoloaded at my application.rb config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realized what was wrong. In my test files, I was including my modules from the `lib` directory, Instead of reopening the module and put the test files in the the module. After doing that rake test:units works perfectly. Test files should remain in `test/unit` directory

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this as well. There are (at least?) 2 possible problems:

- **Your module is not in the autoload path**

Look in `config/application.rb` for this line:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)
```

If it's commented, uncomment it. This line will turn on autoloading for all files inside `extras`, and all files in subdirectories of `extras`, too. It's probably safest to move your modules into `extras`, but if you really want to leave them in `lib`, change the line to be:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras #{config.root}/lib)
```

- **Your module is in the autoload path, but not named the way Rails expects**

(see this: [Rails 2.3.5: How does one access code inside of lib/directory/file.rb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796027/rails-2-3-5-how-does-one-access-code-inside-of-lib-directory-file-rb))

By convention, Rails wants the name of your module to match the directory hierarchy and the filename. So the file `extras/mylib.rb` would be expected to contain

```
module Mylib   # not MyLib or My_lib
  ...
end
```

This works for subdirectories as well, so a file `extras/mydir/mylib.rb` should contain:

```
module Mydir
  module Mylib  # or class Mylib
    ...
  end
end
```

This naming convention is the same as what Rails expects for controllers and models. Underscores in the filename turn into a camelcase class/module name. A file called `my_lib.rb` would be expected to have a `module MyLib` in it (but not `Mylib`).

**NOTE** that *autoload* does not mean that the module is automatically loaded at startup; rather, it's automatically loaded when it's first used. So even if you have some code like `puts "hi from mylib"` at the top of your `mylib.rb` file, you won't see that print until your code uses `Mylib` somewhere.

Finally, if you really want your modules to load *at startup*, go create a file called `config/initializers/force_load_libraries.rb` and put this in there:

```
Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/extras/force_load/*.rb").each { |f| require f }
```

Now go put your libs in `extras/force_load` and they should load when Rails starts up.